# Spotfire Piechart only to show top 5 Percentage in Chart

Tags: pie-chart, percentage, spotfire

I hope you can help. The issue I am facing is that I only want my Pie chart to show wedges for the top 5%

In screen shot 1 you can see that my pie charts show more wedges that the top 5% i want to show only the top 5%.

Can my Pie Chart be manipulated to show this?

I am guessing that I can change it with custom expression but I just dont know what syntax to use. You can see in Screen shot 2 what the Pie Chart is sized by

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Screen Shot 1
[image]

Screen Shot 2[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy and is built in luckily.

```
Right Click On your Chart > Properties > Show/Hide Items > Add...
```

Then just select `Top` for the Rule Type and enter `5`. This would show the top 5.

If you want the top 5% then just change the `Column` value (just above the Rule Type) to what ever expression you are using to find the top 5%... i.e. `Sum([Column]) / Count()`

Comment: Hi scsimon: This worked perfectly thank you so much. Mush respect from Dublin :-) I hope you have a great day :-)

Comment: Cheers mate! Have a pint for me!

Comment: Ha Ha its nice and warm here today so it will be Cider and ice :-) Too hot for the Black Stuff (Guinness) ;-P